# Как передать переменную из первой форму в форму 3

Tags: c#, winforms, переменные

Я начинаю изучать C#, делаю простенькие программы и учусь на этом )

Я создал две формы `Form1` и `Form3`, пытаюсь передать значение `radioButton`, которое может быть `true` или `false`.

Код Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public void Otvet1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (VariantNeVern1.Checked || VariantNeVern2.Checked || VariantVern.Checked)
        {
            Hide();
            Form2 Vopros = new Form2();                
            Vopros.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Выбирите ответ");
        Close();
    }

    private void VariantNeVern1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 Vopros = new Form3();
        Vopros.Owner = this;
    }
}
```

Код Form3:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1 main = new Form1();
        Rezult.Text = Convert.ToString(main.VariantNeVern1);//тут косяк
    }

    private void CloseTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Я должен получить результат `true` или `false`, чтобы убедиться работает или нет, постоянно получаю `false`, а по логике - если я выделил `radioButton` с именем `VariantNeVern1`, должен получить `true`.

Comment: Почитай про свойства и что это такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя пока проблемы с ООП.

```
Form1 main = new Form1(); // на самом деле, косяк тут
Rezult.Text = Convert.ToString(main.VariantNeVern1);//тут не косяк
```

Ты создаёшь новый объект типа Form1. Он не имеет никакого отношения к главной форме твоего приложения. Соответственно, все контролы в нём находятся в начальном состоянии и ты передаёшь всегда False. Если это не случайная ошибка, рекомендую начать с консольного приложения, но с хорошей объектной моделью и кучей маленьких классиков, каждый из которых имеет свою область ответственности. После этого возвращайся в мир UI.

Если говорить о WinForms, то на дворе 2017. И если есть желание развиваться в направлении UI, рекомендую начать сразу с WPF.

Если говорить о самом способе передачи элемента управления, то в мире UI так не делают. Есть несколько основных шаблонов проектирования, которых стараются придерживаться (только без фанатизма). Например MVC (модель, представление, контроллер) и MVVMC (модель, модель представления, представление, контроллер).

В твоём случае не хватает именно класса модели, которая хранит определенные состояния. Важно понимать, что если ты не пишешь редактор интерфейса, то тебе не нужно передавать между формами кнопку. Тебе нужно передать некоторый режим работы, за который она отвечает.

```
public enum Variants
{
  Correct = 1,
  Incorrect = 2
}
```

Эти состояния хранятся в некотором модельном классе, контексте, который шарится между всеми желающими.

```
public class Model
{
  public Variants CurrentVariant {get;set;}
}
```

И вот эту модель ты один раз инициализируешь, а затем передаешь во все формы, которые должны общаться между собой (на самом деле, обычно, передаёшь контроллер - более умную сущность, которая содержит не только данные, но и некоторые операции, действия, но об этом ты прочитаешь в гугле по запросу MVC).

```
Model model = new Model();
Form1 form1 = new Form1(model);
Form2 form2 = new Form2(model);
```

А они уже её используют и сохраняют в ней сотояние кнопки, не как "Checked", а как конкретное состояние системы.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private readonly Model _model;

  public Form1(Model model)
  {
    _model = model;
  }

  private void VariantNeVern1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      bool isChecked = VariantNeVern1.Checked;
      Variants variant = isChecked ? Variants.Incorrect : Variants.Correct;
      _model.CurrentVariant = variant;
  }
}
```

Соответственно вторая форма может получить доступ к этому значению.

В какой момент создавать формы и как передать между ними модель данных или контроллер - это та самая проблема, ради которой и придумывают шаблоны проектирования.

Прочитай про MVC, большая часть вопросов отпадёт. Если перейдёшь на WPF, прочитай про Binding и INotifyPropertyChanged. Когда освоишься, можешь посмотреть в сторону более строгого и тяжеловестного MVVMC.

Ну а в рамках твоего примера, можешь либо создать обе формы вначале, а затем отображать и скрывать их методами Show и Hide, при этом во второй подпишись на событие Shown и в этот момент считывай значение из модели; либо создавать вторую форму внутри первой и передавать модель из неё, тогда инициализацию своего "Re*z*ult" ты можешь оставить в конструкторе, опять же, получая значение из модели.

Надеюсь, что смог помочь, а не только запутать.

Comment: по поводу WPF согласен. можно даже UWP / Xamarin пощупать. Я сразу с UWP начал, например

Comment: Lunar Whisper, Спасибо. понимаю через раз, дело в том что это мой первый язык программирования вообще, много чего не понятно, значит плохо у меня с ООП, я изучаю C# уже где-то месяц :) Что можно почитать или посмотреть видео уроки, где доступным языком для чайников раскладывают все по полочкам. Получается мне пока рано в мир UI и работать пока нужно исключительно с консолью.

Comment: "C# 5.0 in a Nutshell", "CLR via C#"

http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/04/best-books-on-cnet.html